How to calculate Christoffel symbols and curvature for the Alcubierre metric
I am trying to calculate the the christoffel symbols and a few other quantities for the following metric using the code from
https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~gravitybook/mathematica.html

Using the code from Difficulties on Mathematica code to solve Christoffel Symbols of a particular metric
I get the same result, which does not use the excplicit form of f.
What I would like to do is incorporate f and $r_{0}$ explicitly. I tried defining them through
f[t_, x_, y_,  z_] := (ArcTanh[\[Sigma]  ((Sqrt[(x - xs[t])^2 + y^2 + z^2]) + R)] - ArcTanh[\[Sigma]  ((Sqrt[(x - xs[t])^2 + y^2 + z^2]) -  R)])/(2  ArcTanh[\[Sigma]  R])
and
Sqrt[(x - xs[t])^2 + y^2 + z^2]
but unfortunately it does not work.
Many thanks in advance!
I tried to run both codes, but unfortunately they don't work for me:


What version of Mathematica do you run?

@Alex Trounev This was done using version 14.

It looks like some bug of your system. Maybe you need to reboot Mathematica.

The Christoffelsymbols now seem to work.

We can use for instance this code (some results shown in pictures)
Clear [coord, metric, inversemetric, affine, riemann, ricci, scalar, \
einstein, t, x, y, z]

n = 4;
coord = {t, x, y, z}; r = 
 Sqrt[(x - xs[t])^2 + y^2 + 
   z^2]; f = (Tanh[sigma (r + R)] - 
    Tanh[sigma (r - R)])/(2  Tanh[sigma R]);
metric = {{-c^2 + vs[t]^2 f^2, vs[t]  f, 0, 0}, {vs[t]  f, 1, 0, 
    0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};

inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]];

affine := 
  affine = 
   Simplify[
    Table[(1/2)*
      Sum[inversemetric[[i, 
         s]]*(D[metric[[s, j]], coord[[k]]] + 
          D[metric[[s, k]], coord[[j]]] - 
          D[metric[[j, k]], coord[[s]]]), {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
      1, n}, {k, 1, n}]];


listaffine := 
  Table[If[
    UnsameQ[affine[[i, j, k]], 
     0], {ToString[\[CapitalGamma][i - 1, j - 1, k - 1]], 
     affine[[i, j, k]]}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, j}];


TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listaffine], Null], 2], 
 TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]


But expressions for Riemann, Ricci and Einstein tensor become very complicated. It is why we recommend this code
Clear [coord, metric, inversemetric, affine, riemann, ricci, scalar, \
einstein, t, x, y, z]

n = 4;
coord = {t, x, y, 
   z};(*r=Sqrt[(x-xs[t])^2+y^2+z^2];f=(Tanh[sigma (r+R)]-Tanh[sigma \
(r-R)])/(2 Tanh[sigma R]);*)
metric = {{-c^2 + vs[t]^2 f[t, x, y, z]^2, vs[t] f[t, x, y, z], 0, 
    0}, {vs[t] f[t, x, y, z], 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};

inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]];

affine := 
  affine = 
   Simplify[
    Table[(1/2)*
      Sum[inversemetric[[i, 
         s]]*(D[metric[[s, j]], coord[[k]]] + 
          D[metric[[s, k]], coord[[j]]] - 
          D[metric[[j, k]], coord[[s]]]), {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
      1, n}, {k, 1, n}]];


listaffine := 
  Table[If[
    UnsameQ[affine[[i, j, k]], 
     0], {ToString[\[CapitalGamma][i - 1, j - 1, k - 1]], 
     affine[[i, j, k]]}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, j}];
riemann := 
  riemann = 
   Simplify[
    Table[D[affine[[i, j, l]], coord[[k]]] - 
      D[affine[[i, j, k]], coord[[l]]] + 
      Sum[affine[[s, j, l]]*affine[[i, k, s]] - 
        affine[[s, j, k]]*affine[[i, l, s]], {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, 
      n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}, {l, 1, n}]];

listriemann := 
  Table[If[
    UnsameQ[riemann[[i, j, k, l]], 0], {ToString[R[i, j, k, l]], 
     riemann[[i, j, k, l]]}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}, {l, 1, 
    k - 1}];

TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listriemann], Null], 2], 
 TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]
ricci := 
 ricci = Simplify[
   Table[Sum[riemann[[i, j, i, l]], {i, 1, n}], {j, 1, n}, {l, 1, n}]]

listricci := 
  Table[If[
    UnsameQ[ricci[[j, l]], 0], {ToString[R[j, l]], 
     ricci[[j, l]]}], {j, 1, n}, {l, 1, n}];

TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listricci], Null], 2], 
 TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]
scalar = 
 Simplify[
  Sum[inversemetric[[i, j]]*ricci[[i, j]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]]

einstein := einstein = Simplify[ricci - (1/2)*scalar*metric]

listeinstein := 
  Table[If[
    UnsameQ[einstein[[j, l]], 0], {ToString[G[j, l]], 
     einstein[[j, l]]}], {j, 1, n}, {l, 1, n}];

TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listeinstein], Null], 2], 
 TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]

For scalar curvature we have
scalar 
Out[]=
(1/(2*c^2))*(-4*Derivative[1][vs][t]*Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][f][t, x, y, z] + 
   vs[t]^2*(Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][f][t, x, y, z]^2 + 
     Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][f][t, x, y, z]^2 + 4*Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][f][t, x, y, z]^
       2 + 4*f[t, x, y, z]*Derivative[0, 2, 0, 0][f][t, x, y, z]) - 
   4*vs[t]*Derivative[1, 1, 0, 0][f][t, x, y, z])

In a special case of the Alcubierre metric we have
f = Function[{t, x, y, 
   z}, (ArcTanh[\[Sigma]   ((Sqrt[(x - xs[t])^2 + y^2 + z^2]) + R)] - 
     ArcTanh[\[Sigma]   ((Sqrt[(x - xs[t])^2 + y^2 + z^2]) - 
         R)])/(2   ArcTanh[\[Sigma]   R])]; scalar // Simplify



Thank you! So If I want to use compositions of functions I have to introduce them as coordinates?

I tried your code. Unfortunately something went wrong.

@Hans First please tell me what is wrong?

@AlexTrounev He updated the question
